# If statement as vector/subsetting in R

Tags: r, if-statement, vectorization

I have two datasets, example of those given below.

```
DF1
Level
 10
 20
 10
 34

DF2
LevelLow     LevelHigh    Speed
   0            10          24
   11           20          29
   21           30          31
   31           40          36
```

I want to be able to add a column in DF1 which holds the speed of the Level if it's between the LevelLow and LevelHigh boundary. An example of the final dataset (DF1) is given below.

```
DF1
Level    Speed
 10        24
 20        29
 10        24
 34        36
```

I think I know how to do this via an if statement but how would I go about doing this in another way? I believe that vectorisation speeds up the process? If any of you know of any other way to do this then please let me know :)

Comment: Try `DF2$Speed[findInterval(DF1$Level,DF2$LevelLow)]`.

Comment: That's perfect :) Thanks!